# Include email in JWT using Auth0Lock

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm using Angular 2, Auth0 and Auth0 Lock.

When I authenticate, I want the JWT Auth0 sends back to include the user's email address.

How can this be accomplished? (The instructions in the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/sending-authentication-parameters#scope-string-) seem not to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how I was instantiating `lock` before:

```
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {});
```

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
    auth: {
      params: { scope: 'openid email' }
    }
  });
```

This will include the email in the token.

Note that the following will *not* work:

```
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
    auth: {
      params: { scope: 'email' }
    }
  });
```

Not only will it not work but it will fail in a somewhat mysterious way.